# Генерация подсказок

Tags: java, android, activity, условия

На главном экране приложения должны быть подсказки, как в Google now.
Подсказки выдаются исходя из различных условий.

Как и где проверять эти условия лучше? При запуске сделать проверки по всем условиям?

```
if(userStupid) new Card("Вы очень умный");
if(userVeryStupid) new Card("Вам следует написать книгу");
```

Мне кажется это немного глупо - делать такие проверки каждый раз.

Как бы вы реализовали?

Answer (score 2):

Может сделать флаг, который меняется, если условия изменились? Тогда тебе нужно будет его только проверять. А флаг менять с помощью событий. К тому же флаг может быть одновременно и меткой, где что изменилось.
т.е. например значение 0 - все неизменно. значение 1 - изменилось условие 1. Значение 10 - изменилось условие 2. И так далее.
Если изменились два первых условия - то получится значение 11.